# Gradle compileJava Task keeps failing

Tags: java, gradle, osgi, bnd

alright i've been hiting my head against the wall for quite sometime now, and now i dont even know what to search for to find a solution, here are my files

build.gradle

```
    //Applying the Gradle BND Plugin for Workspace Builds
    //https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle/README.md
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.gradle:${bnd_version}"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'biz.aQute.bnd.workspace'
apply plugin: 'java'

    // Repositorios, aguante Maven Central.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    /* Excluded, uso la dependecia de otro lado ahora.
    flatDir {
        dirs '/home/feddericokz/devTools/Equinox/Equinox-Oxygen-1a/plugins'
    }
    */
}

    // Dependencias
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/org.osgi.core
    compile group: 'org.osgi', name: 'org.osgi.core', version: '6.0.0'
}
```

settings.gradle

```
/*
 * This settings file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * The settings file is used to specify which projects to include in your build.
 * In a single project build this file can be empty or even removed.
 *
 * Detailed information about configuring a multi-project build in Gradle can be found
 * in the user guide at https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
 */

/*
// To declare projects as part of a multi-project build use the 'include' method
include 'shared'
include 'api'
include 'services:webservice'
*/

rootProject.name = 'bndWorkspace'

include 'com.feddericokz.helloworld'
```

when trying to run gradle jar from the command line, i get an error as it the compiler cant find the osgi dependencies to compile the classes

```
Task :com.feddericokz.helloworld:compileJava FAILED
/home/feddericokz/testingDir/bndWorkspace/com.feddericokz.helloworld/src/com/feddericokz/helloworld/HelloWorldActivator.java:3: error: package org.osgi.framework does not exist
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
                         ^
/home/feddericokz/testingDir/bndWorkspace/com.feddericokz.helloworld/src/com/feddericokz/helloworld/HelloWorldActivator.java:4: error: package org.osgi.framework does not exist
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
                         ^
/home/feddericokz/testingDir/bndWorkspace/com.feddericokz.helloworld/src/com/feddericokz/helloworld/HelloWorldActivator.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
public class HelloWorldActivator implements BundleActivator {
                                            ^
  symbol: class BundleActivator
/home/feddericokz/testingDir/bndWorkspace/com.feddericokz.helloworld/src/com/feddericokz/helloworld/HelloWorldActivator.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
                      ^
  symbol:   class BundleContext
  location: class HelloWorldActivator
/home/feddericokz/testingDir/bndWorkspace/com.feddericokz.helloworld/src/com/feddericokz/helloworld/HelloWorldActivator.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
                     ^
  symbol:   class BundleContext
  location: class HelloWorldActivator
/home/feddericokz/testingDir/bndWorkspace/com.feddericokz.helloworld/src/com/feddericokz/helloworld/HelloWorldActivator.java:7: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/home/feddericokz/testingDir/bndWorkspace/com.feddericokz.helloworld/src/com/feddericokz/helloworld/HelloWorldActivator.java:12: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
7 errors


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':com.feddericokz.helloworld:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Bnd workspace model build, then you *must* configure the build path through each project's `bnd.bnd` file using the `-buildpath` Bnd instruction. Then the Bnd gradle plugin will use that information to program the configurations for java compilation.

Your example shows setting a compile dependency for the root gradle project which is wrong since (1) you should be using `-buildpath` in the project's `bnd.bnd` file and (2) it is done in the root project which is not meaningful to any child projects like your `com.feddericokz.helloworld` project.

So change your build.gradle file to not apply the 'java' plugin to the root project and not set compile dependencies for the root project and change your Bnd workspace so that the workspace (`cnf`) has configured repositories to access the desired bundles, for example https://github.com/osgi/enroute.workspace/blob/4070ff6668a1ee79b9b01cfa4caab86869247e7b/cnf/ext/enroute.bnd#L22-L28, and then set each project's `bnd.bnd` file to have the desired bundles on the `-buildpath`.

Comment: This was extra tricky for me because the bundle I depended on was already in the `-testpath`. So it ran in Eclipse unit tests, but not in Gradle builds where it needed to be on the `-buildpath`.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if `bnd_version` is defined in this line:

```
classpath "biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.gradle:${bnd_version}"
```

Consider adding a `gradle.properties` file with:

```
bnd_version=3.5.0
```

(or whatever version is apporpriate). As best as I can reproduce your situation, my example works for me with this.

Comment: i have it defined like you said, sorry i forgot to add it to the question, still doesnt work. :(